# How does Athena match data to the correct fields when creating a table from Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm still getting to grips with Athena, so apologies if this question doesn't make sense. I'm trying to create a table in Athena from a csv file I have uploaded to my Amazon S3 bucket. During the table creation process on Athena, I need to define field names and datatypes. How are these fields matched with those stored in the Amazon S3 bucket? Is it just the order in which they appear in the csv?

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed depending on the order.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the data format and the serde used. For CSV data, columns are mapped by index. The same goes for the regex and grok serde, as well as ORC. JSON, Avro, and Parquet is instead mapped by name.

Grok, ORC and Parquet can be configured to be either index or name, but the above are the defaults.